# Matlab: find length of specific parts of array given a threshold

Tags: matlab

Consider a vector of ones and zeros shown in the following plot

[image]

How can I obtain without using loops the lengths of the ones/zeros sections in such an array?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you mean. What would you want as output from a vector [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1]? Would you expect one vector detailing the length of each section [3 2 1 1 1 4]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff` and `find` like that:

```
a = [ 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1];
result = diff(find([ 1 diff(a) 1]))

result =

 3     2     2     4     1     1
```

Or, other example:

```
a = [ 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
result = diff(find([ 1 diff(a) 1]))

result =

 2     4     1     1     1     5     3
```